# How can I access a column of other table with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables `ProductionLine` and `Machine`. In the `Machine` table, I have a foreign key to `ProductionLine` named `productionLine`.

I want to access the column `KeyId` in `ProductionLine` from the `Machine` table.
my Machine Class:

```
[Column("FldKeyId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int MyKeyId { get; set; }
    [Column("FldCode")]
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int MyMachineCode
    {
        get { return _MachineCode; }
        set { _MachineCode = value; }
    }
    [Column("FldName")]
    [Required]
    public string MyName
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    [Column("FldDescription")]
    [Required]
    public string MyDescription
    {
        get { return _Desc; }
        set { _Desc = value; }
    }
    [Column("FldModifiedUserId")]
    [Required]
    public int ModifiedUserId { get; set; }
    [Column("FldModificationDate")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
    [Column("FldDeleteFlag")]
    [Required]
    public int DeleteFlag { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ProductionLine ProductionLine { get; set; }
```

and that's DbContext Class:

```
public DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
```

I have this code, but it is throwing an error:

```
Machine _SelectedMachine;
_SelectedMachine = (cmbMachines.SelectedItem as Machine);
int Mid = _SelectedMachine.ProductionLine.MyKeyId;
dgvcolCompany.DataSource = ProductionLine.GetMachineLine(Mid);
```

and method `getMachineLine`:

```
public static List<ProductionLine> GetMachineLine(int KeyId)
{
   return new ContexManager().ProductionLines.Where(c => c.MyKeyId == KeyId && c.DeleteFlag == 0).ToList();
}
```

When running this code, on the line

```
int Mid=...
```

I get this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What do I have to do?

My tables are generated by EF code-first
 -Problem is How to access ProductionLine's KeyId From Machine's productionLine

Comment: Can you please show the Entity Type Configuration and class definition for Machine?

Comment: @RichaGarg My Code Is Updated

Comment: you have not mentioned the ` [ForeignKey]` attribute over the `ProductionLine` property. How are you configuring it as a foreign key?

Comment: Have  you used Fluent APIs for the foreign key configuration?

Comment: Also, declare the property `PropertyLine` as virtual

Comment: no i dont use Fluent APIs but when i have field with ProductionLine data type it have worked as FK

Comment: now the Problem is How to access ProductionLine's KeyId From Machine's productionLine

Comment: Just mark the property as virtual and see the results!

Comment: public `virtual` ProductionLine ProductionLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the property `ProductionLine` as virtual. Also add the foreign key attribute on it.

```
[ForeignKey]
```

`public virtual ProductionLine ProductionLine;`

P.S please mark it as an answer if it helped

Comment: how to make it virtual?

Comment: i want set ForeignKey Attribute for productionLine But Migraton don't let an problem is.... the Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names

Comment: Declare the property as:    public virtual ProductionLine ProductionLine;

Comment: Don't add the foreign key attribute. Just declare it as virtual

Comment: Are you getting the same error after declaring it `virtual`?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `[ForeignKey("ForeignKeyName")]` attribute above `ProductionLine`
And make it virtual to make `Lazy Loading` possible.
Or if you don't want lazy loading use `Include("ProductionLine")` when getting a machine.

OffTopic: Your namings are bad. Entity Framework uses a "Convention based" approach. So a primary key of a class named `Machine`, should be called `Id` instead of `MyKeyId`

Comment: how to make it virtual?

Comment: i want set ForeignKey Attribute for productionLine But Migraton don't let an problem is.... the Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names